# Is there any way to insert symbol in some place in string using regex in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a string, that illustrates an math expression and before evaluating it i need to make some preprocessing.

I want to insert '*', if somewhere in my string exist sequence like "\d(", where \d - is any digit.

Is there a way to do it using c# Regex? I understand, how i can do it in Python, for example, but i'm kinda new in sharp =(

Comment: It would help incredibly if you gave us examples of the “math expression”, what results you want, and how you did it in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Regex.Replace` with reusing of match. `$1` stands for content of first pair of parentheses. So in the first pair I have expression `\d\(`

```
string s = "asdlk1()3412a(123)";
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"(\d\()", @"$1*"); // asdlk1(*)3412a(123)
```

There's a [playground](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/0NXJow).